# How to figure out how the window is resized in a classical Windows application

Tags: windows

Suppose you get an open source classical Windows desktop (i.e. with WinMain) application and you want to change the default size of the window, how to find out where to edit in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in `WM_SIZE` branch in `WndProc`, then in the callstack you can instantly locate some source in your project that uses some API to change the window size.